# When will a Taylor series analytically continue a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-continuation

Suppose we have a complex-analytic function $f$ given by
\begin{equation}
 \tag{1}
 f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\, a_n \mspace{.5mu} (z-z_0)^n, \qquad a_n \in \mathbb{C},
\end{equation}
where $z_0$ is a point in the complex plane.
It is then straightforward to show that $f$ must be absolutely convergent in an open disk $D$ centred at $z_0$ and extending to at least one singularity $s_0$ at the circumference $\partial D$.

Since $f$ is analytic, we can write down its Taylor series expansion about *any* point $z_1\in D$.
This amounts to introducing the function
\begin{equation}
 \tag{2}
 f_1(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \, b_n \mspace{.5mu} (z-z_1)^n , \qquad b_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(z_1)}{n!} ,
\end{equation}
where $f^{(n)}(z_1)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$ at $z_1$.
Again we see that this new function must be absolutely convergent on some open disk $D_1$, centred at $z_1$ rather than $z_0$.
Using Cauchy's integral formula, it is possible to show that the radius of $D_1$ — which we will call $r_1$ — must be
\begin{equation}
 \tag{3}
 r_1 \geq |s_0-z_0|-|z_1-z_0|,
\end{equation}
since $f_1(z)=f(z)$ within a disk $D_1'$ strictly contained in $D$ and centred on $z_1$.

---

Given this setup, my question is simply this:
Assuming $s_0$ is the closest non-removable singularity of $f$ to $z_1$, what additional requirements can we put on $f$ in order to be able to show that $r_1\geq|s_0-z_1|$, and how would we go about doing so?
Or in other words, when will the Taylor series $f_1$ analytically continue $f$ to $D_1 \nsubseteq D$?

---

**Edit**: The original wording was too restrictive; exchanged a "must" with a "can" to make my intent clearer.
I would be happy with sufficient (non-trivial) requirements even if they are not, in fact, necessary.
My main goal is to obtain some justification for the assertion, seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788684/convergence-of-taylor-series-the-claim-that-it-fails-to-converge-to-fz-outs?rq=1) and [elsewhere](https://youtu.be/CjSKmcWRFzE?t=1860), that "a Taylor series of $f$ about $z_1$ will converge on a disk extending to the nearest singularity of $f$".

Comment: When the analytic continuation exists. Not sure what you expect? For any open set there is a function analytic on it and not elsewhere.

Comment: @reuns: Well, I was hoping there might be a theorem about *when* the analytic continuation exists ... Though if that is not the case, that is useful to know too, I guess.

Comment: "What are the standard methods to prove that an analytic continuation exists" is a difficult question, I don't think there is any standard method, only particular cases for each kind of function, beside the low level stuffs such as Cauchy integral formula, radius of convergence, identity theorem, Morera's theorem, Schwarz reflection principle, monodromy theorem, Lagrange inversion, Riemann's theorem on removable singularities, residue theorem, argument principle..

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition for a point $\zeta\in \partial D$ to be a regular point, i.e. a pain across which $f$ can be analytically continued, involves exactly a particular instance of the function $f_1$, namely the one where $z_1$ is contained on the line segment joining $\zeta$ and $z_0$, and is due to Fabry. A brief description of it is in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353040/are-there-any-necessary-conditions-of-lacunary-functions-known/354417#354417): note that, as recalled in the cited answer, this not the unique existing necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: As a further note I can say that the knowledge of these methods is not so widely diffuse because they are difficult to apply in practice due to the complex calculations involved.

Comment: I'm sure this is thoroughly explained in Needham's Visual Complex Analysis. I kind of remember a section named "the mystery of power series ".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I checked, and Nedham's book does indeed have a section titled "The mystery of real power series", but, alas, it does not explore when a Taylor series can be used to continue an analytic function, only why the Taylor series of some functions [like $1/(1+x^2)$] have a smaller domain than their "parent functions". From what I could see, it did not look like my question was adressed in other parts either. Still, looked like a nice resource!